# Noob question; Is it possible to add smooth-scroll effect after keypress event on a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried smooth-scrolling across a page with the `click` event and it works, also with CSS, but I tried it with `keypress` event but the smooth-scrolling doesn't seem to work. Here's my code-snippet;

```html
<body>
  <div class="first-section">
  </div>
  <div id="second-section" class="second-section">
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    document.querySelector('.second-section').scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Maybe try it with the keyPress event listener

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, had to add the
`e.preventdefault();`
method to prevent the default behavior which is a straight jump to the specified section. Then the smooth scroll will come into place.